# How to position brace relative to a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put brace and its mirror at left and right side of a rectangle with some horizontal gap between rectangle and braces. I used following code but it puts gap only at north side and not the south side. How to put a horizontal gap between brace and rectangle at both north and south sides.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes,shadows,arrows.meta,arrows,decorations.markings,trees,positioning,decorations.markings,calc,fit,chains,intersections,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,text depth = 6cm, minimum width=7cm] (auth) {};
\node[draw,text depth = 3cm, minimum width=6cm] at ([yshift=-3cm]auth.north) (gen) {};
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (gen.north east)+(0.5cm, 0cm) -- (gen.south east)+(0.5cm, 0cm);
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (gen.north west)+(-0.5cm,0cm) -- (gen.south west)+(-0.5cm, 0cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that manual adjustment like `(gen.north east)+(0.5cm, 0cm)` is a goof thing here. I think that it's better to use `(gen.north -| auth.east)` which takes the y-coordinate from `gen.north` and the x-coordinate from `auth.east`. Then you can use `raise` parameter to adjust the position of the braces.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
      node[draw,minimum height = 6cm, minimum width=7cm] (auth) {}
      node[draw,minimum height = 3cm, minimum width=6cm] (gen) {};
    \begin{scope}[red, decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=3pt}]
      \draw[decorate] (gen.north -| auth.east) -- (gen.south -| auth.east);
      \draw[decorate, decoration={mirror}] (gen.north -| auth.west) -- (gen.south -| auth.west);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also corrected in your code:

- all useless libraries (you have included `decorations.markings` two times!),
- the manual adjustments for the position of the `(gen)` node,
- replaced `text depth` by `minimum height`,
- introduced a `scope` for all common decorations.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because `(a) +(5mm,0) -- (b) +(5mm,0)` means

1. place pen at `a`
2. move pen to the point 5mm right of `a`
3. draw line to `b`
4. move pen to point 5mm right of `b`

You have many options though.

- the syntax of the `calc` library, e.g. `($(gen.north east)+(0.5cm, 0cm)$)`
- the `raise` keyword
- `shift`/`xshift`/`yshift` in the last coordinate, as percusse mentioned in his (now deleted) answer, e.g. `(gen.south east)+(0,-0.5cm) -- ([shift={(0,-0.5cm)}]gen.south west)`.
- if your purpose is to have the braces along the edge of the outer rectangle, you can use perpendicular coordinates, as demonstrated below

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,text depth = 6cm, minimum width=7cm] (auth) {};
\node[draw,text depth = 3cm, minimum width=6cm] at ([yshift=-3cm]auth.north) (gen) {};

% calc library
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] 
        ($(gen.north east)+(0.8cm, 0cm)$) -- ($(gen.south east)+(0.8cm, 0cm)$);

% raise key
\draw [decorate,
       decoration={
          brace,
          amplitude=5pt,
          mirror,
          raise=8mm} % <--- raise key to move brace away
       ] (gen.north west) -- (gen.south west);


% shift one coordinate
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (gen.south east)+(0,-0.5cm) -- ([shift={(0,-0.5cm)}]gen.south west);


% if the brace should be along the outer rectangle
% perpendicular coordinates
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}]
     (gen.north east-|auth.east) -- (gen.south east-|auth.east);

\draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror}]
     (gen.north west-|auth.west) -- (gen.south west-|auth.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```